# Using a string variable with FormulaR1C1 works unless it starts with a number

Tags: string, vba, excel

Up until recently I've been successfully using the following macro to write a formula to a cell in a spreadsheet:

```
Sub insertFormula()

Dim apple As String
Dim orange As String

apple = "Z9Y8X7"
orange = "A1B2C3"

ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('Data Dump'!C25, " & apple & ", 'Data Dump'!C6, " & orange & " )"

End Sub
```

This usually results in the following formula appearing in the active cell (which is what I want it to do).

```
=COUNTIFS('Data Dump'!$Y:$Y, Z9Y8X7, 'Data Dump'!$F:$F, A1B2C3 )
```

However, when I change one of the variables so that it starts with a number, for example:

```
apple = "1Z9Y8X7"
```

I am prompted with the following error when attempting to execute the FormulaR1C1 line

> Run-time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

The macro always runs perfectly if I use strings with a range of alphanumeric characters, however as soon as the first character is a number it returns the above error.

Why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding quotes around your string:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=COUNTIFS('Data Dump'!C25, " & Chr(34) & apple & Chr(34) & ", 'Data Dump'!C6, " & Chr(34) & orange & Chr(34) & " )"
```

Adding quotes allows the Formula reader to recognize the string as a string.